# Matlab : How to make label output from interval data?

Tags: matlab, intervals, label

So i have this data:

```
 A= 
2
4
8
9
4
6
1
3
```

And 3 interval

```
B=
1 4
5 8
9 12
```

How to make an output like this

```
Output=
1
1
2
3
1
2
1
1
```

The output is based on the interval

Comment: How is Output calculated from A and B?

Comment: for example for first A data whic is 2, we must search in all interval that exist [1 4] 2nd [5 8] 3rd [9 12], beacause 2 is in 1st interval so the output is 1 (represent 1st interval)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it in several ways. for example, with `arrayfun`:

```
 A = [2 4 8 9 4 6 1 3].';
 B = [1 4;
     5 8;
     9 12];
 res = arrayfun(@(x) find((x >= B(:,1)) & (x <= B(:,2))),A);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the interval always has the same length, as in your case 4, you can solve it as follows:

```
Output=ceil(A/4);
```

If it is not the case, and if not all numbers necessarily fall between any of the intervals, you can compute it as follows. A zero is outputted if a number does not fall within any of the intervals.

```
% example entry
A=[2 3 4 8 9 4 6 1 3]';
B=[1 4;5 7;9 12]';

Arep=A(:,ones(size(B,2),1)); % replicate array (alternatively use repmat)
Alog=Arep>=B(1,:)&Arep<=B(2,:); % conditional statements, make logical array
Output=Alog*(1:size(B,2))'; % matrix product with natural array to obtain indices
```

Comment: Error using  <= 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: @MasBiru works for me, maybe you are not running the full example; it could be you have defined A or B as their transpose